# trouble installing drizzlepac

Tags: python, software, astropy

I'm trying to install drizzlepac to follow this tutorial on aligning hst images: https://spacetelescope.github.io/notebooks/notebooks/DrizzlePac/align_to_catalogs/align_to_catalogs.html

However, I get the following errors:

```
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\FAILTZ~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpl00kr2fm'
       cwd: C:\Users\FAILTZ~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1l1f4o5x\drizzlepac
  Complete output (26 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\FAILTZ~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ey64g5zm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 147, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\FAILTZ~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ey64g5zm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\FAILTZ~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ey64g5zm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 249, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\FAILTZ~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ey64g5zm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 23, in <module>
      check_call(['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/spacetelescope/relic.git'])
    File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 358, in check_call
      retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 339, in call
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
      startupinfo)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'e:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\FAILTZ~1.DES\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpl00kr2fm' Check the logs for full command output.
```

This was using pip within an anaconda prompt. If I try to use conda, it can't find the package.

I'm extremely new to python, so I'm sure I'm doing something relatively basic wrong! But I've been bashing my head against this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you should not be using `pip` with Anaconda or you will get into a mess. Unfortunately, that's not the main issue here.

The workbook you linked has a banner at the top that mentions an initialization workbook, which is on [this page](https://spacetelescope.github.io/notebooks/notebooks/DrizzlePac/Initialization/Initialization.html). On that page it states that "Users unfamiliar with Anaconda/Astroconda should see the [documentation](https://astroconda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)."

I am unfamiliar with Astroconda, so I went to the documentation page which lists the following requirements:

> System Requirements
>
> - 64-bit Intel/AMD processor (x86_64)
> - 64-bit Linux (glibc ≥ 2.12) or Mac OS X (≥ 10.7)
> - BASH or ZSH as your default shell environment (T/CSH is NOT supported)

I see from your command line that you are using this on Windows. That is not listed as a supported operating system: the software is Linux/Mac only.

Comment: ah! that's a very simple answer - thanks so much!